# ocaml fixpoint function

Tags: ocaml

So I'm doing an assignment on ocaml and I'm confused on how to write one of the functions fixpoint which is supposed to compare a function and an int x, f(x) and keep comparing them recursively like f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))) until two consecutive values are equal, and it then prints the value.

We're supposed to use the wwhile function we wrote previously which is

```
let rec wwhile (f,b) = match f(b) with
|(integer, boolean) -> if boolean == false then integer 
                       else wwhile (f, integer)
```

The link can be found here

http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa12/cse130-a/homeworks/hw2.html

Its the fixpoint function I"m stuck on.

Comment: I think the usual rule for homework is that you should show some code that you've tried.  Without something to comment on, it's hard to help without just solving the problem.  Assuming you're showing `wwhile` correctly, I'd say your problem is to figure out what the function `f` needs to look like to do what you want.

Comment: boolean == false is not a good expression in 2 points. 1) You should use (=) instead of (==), unless you really need (==), the pointer equality. 2) Comparing boolean is redundant. Write not boolean instead.

Comment: While we're at it, you shouldn't be matching against an expression that only has one case. Use let (integer,boolean) = f(b) in... instead.

Comment: @nlucaroni: please read the tag description of `[homework]`. It's been [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: You don't need to put parentheses around b when applying f to it :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned previously, you shouldn't have only one match case.

After, consider the following :

- It would be interresting to avoid an infinite loop
- You have two case : f(x) = x and f(x) != x, you could use this test in the match, but not only.
- You can match two expression :

  match value1, value2 = value3 with

  | v1case1, v2vase1 -> ...
  | v1case2, v2case2 -> ...

My function works, but it's your homework, so you have to work a little ;-)